# How to to get value of a xml node without the child nodes values appended?

Tags: c#, xml, string, replace, deserialization

How to get value of a xml node without the child nodes values appended?
Innertext gives the values of children appended. Is there any way I can remove that string from value of the parent node? /text() doesn't work because I am deserializing the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ to XML:

```
string xml = "<rootNode><node1><node11>v1</node11></node1></rootNode>";
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XElement xmlElement = xDocument.Element("node11");
string value = xmlElement.Value; // v1
```